# Как работает typedef в этом коде?

Tags: функции, typedef, c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*func)(int a, int b);

int call_func(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

void function(int a, int b, func f);

int main ()
{

    function(5, 2, &call_func);
    system("pause");
}

void function(int a, int b, func f)
{
    int sum = (*f)(a, b);
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

typedef вводит новое имя для типа, и примеры вида `typedef int int32` думаю понятны любому. Ну а что с `typedef int (*func)(int a, int b);` в этом коде, он же должен вместо `func f` подставить `int (int a, int b) f`, а подставляет int f(int a, int b), хотя я не только это не понимаю, а и то, откуда он знает что заменять нужно func, ведь это неполный тип или имя. Описание typedef в интернете заканчиваются на `typedef int int32` или же просто с примером структур и функций или ещё каких сложных типов, но без объяснений. Я уже не знаю что думать, с дефайном было как-то проще.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Comment: [@avp][1], Служебная информация всегда в конце массива и по этому была ошибка когда я перезаписывал её и запускал проект в MSVC? В том коде она у меня в двух ячейках src[63][17] src[63][18], дальше можно с тысячными индексами писать вместо 17 и 18, пока не будет ошибки прав доступа. А когда пытался перезаписать те две ячейки, то ошибка была такая "Это может быть вызвано повреждением кучи и указывает на ошибку в test.exe или в одной из загруженных им DLL.".


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/232/avp

Comment: @mzarb: (2) Технически это и правда кусок памяти в 256 байт, доступный для использования. Массив в C "превращается" в указатель на первый элемент, причём адресная арифметика согласована с индексацией массива: если `float* p = new float[64]`, то `p + 2` указывает на элемент массива с индексом 2, то есть 8-й байт (а не 2-й). (3) да, так и есть. (4) почитайте мой любимый [связанный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/276994). Он на английском, но вы продеритесь сквозь текст и получите удовольствие.

Comment: @avp: формально, запись "мимо" выделенной памяти есть UB, оптимизатор имеет право крешнуть программу. Например, вот что делает Clang: [1](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html), [3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html).

Comment: @VladD, IMHO очевидно, что невесть куда обращаться не надо. Даже и не думал заострять на этом внимание.

А если программа при таких ошибках падает, то **это счастье**. Хуже, когда что-то делает, а результаты *только иногда* неправильные.

Comment: [@VladD][1], Спасибо, буду читать постепенно:).


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/10105/vladd

Comment: @avp: проблема в том, что программа может крешнуться в казалось бы совершенно невозможном и точно неожиданном месте только потому, что в трёх метрах листинга от точки креша было UB. Как раз как в этом коде:

    int dead = *P; // (2) убирается оптимизатором как мёртвый код
    if (P == 0) // (1) убирается оптимизатором из-за пред. строки
        return;
    *P = 4;  // тут креш

Comment: @VladD, если откровенно, не совсем понимаю о чем Вы говорите. Ну, крэшнулась, значит думать надо. 

Если падает в одном месте, то причину найти проще. Если в разных и не всегда, то сложнее. Если ...

Вообще, пустой треп. Напоминает душевные страдания новичка перед спаррингом.

Comment: @avp: ну смотрите, если у вас в коде русским по белому написано

    void Do(int* p)
    {
        if (!p)
            return;
        *p = 4; // (*)
    }

    // много кода
    int* pint;

    // много кода
    int dead = *pint;

    // ещё больше кода
    Do(pint);

и оно крешится в строке `(*)` по разыменованию NULL. Что думать в этом случае? Баг компилятора? Другой поток вмешался? А причина может быть в том, что компилятор заинлайнил вызов `Do` и убрал проверку из-за UB.

В этом случае отладка может оказаться нетривиальной, согласитесь.

---
Хотя наверное да, пустой трёп.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typedef` -- не просто текстовая подстановка. Он работает следующим образом: если X -- имя `typedef`-типа, объявление переменной `X x;` работает как будто бы на этом месте стоит описание типа в `typedef`, где `X` заменено на `x`.

То есть

```
typedef int (*func)(int a, int b);
func f;
```

работает как

```
int (*   /*было func, стало*/ f   )(int a, int b);
```

Comment: [@VladD][1], тогда почему работает код из вот [этого][2] вопроса? Ведь `typedef float M[16];`. То есть здесь `void M_M_SetIdentity(M * src)` будет `float *src[16]`, а здесь `M *mat = new M[sizeof(M)]` будет `float *mat[16] = new float[16][64]` и что это за цирк получается?


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/10105/vladd
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/141878/c-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @mzarb: Смотрите. `M * src` означает, что `*src` имеет тип `M`, то есть, `float *src[16]`, как вы правильно и написали. Теперь, `sizeof(M)` равно, конечно, `16 * sizeof(float) = 64`. `new M[sizeof(M)]` создаёт массив и 64 штук `M`, то есть на `64 * 16` float'ов.

Comment: @mzarb: автор вопроса выделяет больше элементов, чем нужно (64, а нужно всего 16), и использует только первые 16 из них. (Проверка: http://ideone.com/E1mx7S)

Comment: Так эта запись `*mat[16] = new float[16][64]` правильная? А как она работает, просто не видел такую никогда и такой вариант не компилируется у меня. Получается, что `mat` - это массив из 16 указателей на тип float, но инициализируется только одним указателем и то не понятно каким, так как я раньше видел только `new float [size]`, то думал что можно только одну пару квадратных скобок и не пойму как работают эти две пары и как вообще прошла инициализация массива без фигурных скобок.

Comment: @mzarb: Всё просто. `new float[16][64]` выделяет массив из 64-х штук `float[16]`, идущих подряд. Этот массив совместим с указателем на первый элемент, то есть указателем на `float[16]`. Наш `mat` и правда такой указатель: `float (*mat)[16]` означает, что тип `*mat` есть `float[16]`, то есть сам `mat` -- указатель на `float[16]`.

---
Чтобы не вести всю эту арифметику типов в уме, и был придуман `typedef`.

Comment: @VladD, Большое спасибо, вроде разобрался, [вот][1] мой вариант без typedef. Есть ещё пару вопросов:  
1. компилятор сам оборачивает указатели круглыми скобками при использовании typedef?  
2. в этой строчке `new float[64][16];` [64] воспринимается как массив без имени, по этому если бы был typedef, то он бы так же само подставил [16] в конец?  
3. что на самом деле происходит c `new`, он просто берет эти скобки [64] и умножает на эти [16], а потом выделяет память для 1024 элементов?  
4. Почему выделяется память под 1028 элементов, а должна выделяться под 1024?
  [1]: http://ideone.com/jXrj1

Comment: @mzarb: (1) компилятор не работает с текстовым представлением. Пример: если у вас есть функция `int s(int x, int y) { return x * y; }`, и вы её вызываете: `s(1 + 2, 3 + 4)`, компилятор не будет выполнять текстовую подстановку, и вычислять `1 + 2 * 3 + 4`, он будет вести себя как будто бы есть скобки. Видите? То же самое происходит и с typedef. (2) `float[64]` -- такой тип, какой был бы у переменной `x` при объявлении `float x[64]`. (3) опять-таки никаких скобок, компилятор работает с типами, а не с текстовыми представлениями, скобки ему не нужны. (4) почему вы считаете, что выделяется 1028?

Comment: [@VladD][1],  
(2) так `float x[64]` это массив из 64 элементов типа float, а точнее это кусок памяти в 256 байт и переменная x указывает на адрес первого элемента, то есть *(p+0)?  
(3) Получается, что код `new float[64][16]` выделяет двумерный массив на куче, а точнее указатель на адрес первого элемента типа float[16], который в свою очередь содержит адрес значения типа float, весь кусок памяти получается в 4096 байт, а один шаг указателя будет равен 64 байтам и при выводе значения не по индексу `p[i][j]`, а по указателю `*(*(p+i)+j)`  
... 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/10105/vladd

Comment: ...  
сначала сложится адрес указателя p с значением i с шагом 64 байта при +1, потом этот  адрес разыменуется и сложится с адресом j с шагом 4 байта при +1 и снова разыменуется?  
(4)Пробовал записывать по индексу `src[0][1030] = 2.2;` и не было ошибки, но при `src[63][16] = 2.2;` выскакивает, то есть в первом варианте 1030 элементов, а во втором 1024. Хочется видеть как оно устроенно на самом деле, что бы потом не опускать руки в сложных ситуациях, но что-то мне все чаще кажется что ответы на эти вопросы кроются не в самом c++, а возможно где-то в книжках по устройству ОС или ассамблере.

Comment: @mzarb, с чего это Вы решили, что **любая** запись мимо выделенной памяти будет вызывать ошибку?

Смотрите, что получается у Вас с записью в src[1030] и src[1024]. На самом деле это те же адреса, что и src[0][1030] и src[63][16].

В результате вызова new было выделено 4096 байт и последний действительно выделенный элемент это src[1023]. Дальше (очевидно в Вашем тесте) идет еще не распределенная память. В ее начало (скажем 8 или 16 байт) функция new запишет некую *служебную* информацию. 

Запись в src[1024] попортит ее, что и будет обнаружено при следующем new (или delete) 

(продолжение след.

Comment: (продолжение)

А при записи в src[1030] вы пишете в никому не интересную (в конкретном случае) область памяти и в простом тесте это "сходит с рук".

Вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` может использоваться для создания псевдонима не только типа данных:

```
typedef int myinteger;         //myinteger - псевдоним для int
myinteger i;                   //эквивалентно int i;
```

но и указания функций, принимающих переменные указанных типов, и возвращающих переменные указанных типов.
Допустим, нас интересует вид функции, принимающей один `int`, а возвращающей `void`. Как-то более строго обозначить тип функции невозможно, потому что у нее есть тип принимающего значения и тип возвращающего значения, саму внутреннюю логику, очевидно, типизировать нельзя. К примеру, функция типа

```
void func(int);
```

заметим, что слово `func` это не тип, а просто имя, если говорить про типы в данном случае, то они

```
void ....(int);
```

Можно зафиксировать эту комбинацию типов входных и выходных параметров. Только не просто создав псевдоним для типа, как это было с типами переменных, а создав тип указателя на функцию. Указателя, потому что указатель хранит адрес объекта, а имя функции и есть указатель на нее(ее адрес).
Мы можем написать такой указатель на функцию, хранящий в себе типы входных и выходных параметров:

```
void print(int n){
  std::cout << n;
}

int main() {

int n = 10;
void (*funcPointer)(int);   
funcPointer = print;
funcPointer(n);
  
  return 0;
}
```

А теперь, если нам лень писать каждый раз тип создаваемого указателя на функцию? Ведь набор входных и выходных параметров может быть весьма громоздким, и объявление можем повторяться. Для таких случаев используется typedef псевдонима типа указателя на функцию. Мы объявляем тип функции(типы ее входных и выходных параметров, если быть точным):

```
typedef void (*funcType)(int);
```

и теперь перепишем предыдущий пример применяя этот псевдоним типа ф-ции:

```
typedef void (*funcType)(int);

void print(int n){
  std::cout << n;
}

int main() {

int n = 10;
funcType funcPointer;// funcPointer – это указатель на ф-цию, хоть и нет *
funcPointer = print;
funcPointer(n);
  
  return 0;
}
```

То есть в случае `typedef` типа переменной, мы создаем сущность некоторого, созданного нами, типа:

```
typedef int myinteger;
myinteger i;                   //эквивалентно int i;
```

При создании псевдонима типа указателя на функцию, повторю: псевдонима типа, мы в итоге тоже создаем сущность `funcPointer` созданного нами типа `funcType`:

```
typedef void (*funcType)(int);
funcType funcPointer;          //эквивалентно записи void (*funcPointer)(int);
```

Если применить такой абстрактный подход, становится проще понять концепцию `typedef` для функции. А уж потом мы начинаем смотреть, что это за тип, и что за ним скрывается.

Чтобы лучше понять, зачем используются `typedef` для функции, рассмотрим пример:
функция `signal` из `<signal.h>`. Её объявление без <signal.h> `typedef` такое:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

но если мы отдельно создадим псевдоним типа функции:

```
typedef void (*SigCatcher)(int);
```

то то же самое объявление функции `signal` становится проще воспринимать:

```
SigCatcher signal(int sig, SigCatcher func);
```

Часть информации в ответе взята [отсюда](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/31818/typedef-for-function-pointers)